# Icon resolution constrains for android

Tags: android, icons

I'm about to launch my first android application, and our graphic designer asked me for the resolution of the icons. From what I know in iOS there are constrains for the icon resolution, so what I'm asking is if there constrains here although I didn't read such in [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en). Also Should I get different resolutions for different screens or if I have high resolution icons will suffice? thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here i added the drawable image size.Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks.

Don't Create 9-patch images for launcher icons . You have to make separate image for each one.

- drawable-ldpi (120 dpi, Low density screen) - 36px x 36px
- drawable-mdpi (160 dpi, Medium density screen) - 48px x 48px
- drawable-hdpi (240 dpi, High density screen) - 72px x 72px
- drawable-xhdpi (320 dpi, Extra-high density screen) - 96px x 96px
- drawable-xxhdpi (480 dpi, Extra-high density screen) - 144px x 144px
- drawable-xxxhdpi (640 dpi, Extra-high density screen) - 192px x 192px
- web (320 dpi, Extra-high density screen) - 512px x 512px

**Info** : WEB(512 x 512) image is used when you upload your android application on Market.

Please refer the link for More details.

[Android Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

[DesigningResources](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources)