# My project doesnt support multiple devices screen view

Tags: android, xml, size, screen

I have an menuscreen XML. When I open the project wide screen Its not adapted all screen size. How can I overcome this problem.

When I want to add picture about this problem I think I need 10 rep. point :)

Could anyone help me ?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/samsun"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:text="@string/samsun"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/trabzon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:text="@string/trabzon"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/adana"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:text="@string/adana"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/antalya"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:text="@string/antalya"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/izmir"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/izmir"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bursa"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/bursa"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/istanbul1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/gayrettepe"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/istanbul2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/acibadem"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/erzurum"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/erzurum"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/diyarbakir"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/diyarbakir"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ankara"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ankara"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/kayseri"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/kayseri"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alcatel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/alcatel"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/huawei"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/huawei"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backbone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/backbone"
            android:textColor="#FFFF" />



    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, just post a html link to the picture, this would help allot! You only need rep to embed the picture in your message.

Comment: @Mustafa, You can try answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329127/icon-resolution-constrains-for-android/21330125#21330125

Answer (score 1):

In android, to support as much devices as possible, you can supply multiple definitions of one layout. First you need to add those folders into your resources, and for each one you can specify different xml files of the same layout to meet the device screens you want your app to be used on.

Here is an example on how the folder structure might look like:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/layout/main_activity.xml           // For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   // For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   // For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

(in app manifest)

```
<supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"  
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

For more info on supporting multiple screens i strongly recommend reading the google docs about it. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) is a link to the documents. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: You're welcome! I would appreciate if you mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Correct Answer @Chris

Comment: You have to tap the V next to the number 0 with the 2 arrows pointing up & down, but i just noticed there are multiple correct answers, so i'll let you choose, i don't want to claim it like that. But it's always nice to award some reputation if you see people take the time to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your dimensions values-small,values-large,values-xlarge etc.

Don't forget to declare support-screens in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"  
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Reffer to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In android you have to set images in different different drawable as per screen size and make layout as per screen size also.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml(drawable also like layout) ---- default layout. 
res/layout-layout-hdpi/my_layout.xml ---- layout for hdpi screen size 
res/layout-layout-large-hdpi/my_layout.xml ---- layout for large hdpi screen size 
res/layout-layout-mdpi/my_layout.xml ---- layout for mdpi screen size(normal tables also) 
res/layout-layout-Xdpi/my_layout.xml ---- layout for Xhdpi screen Size(high resolution)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can proceed as following

res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density


<supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"  
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
```