# Android app UI issue with different screen sizes and resolutions

Tags: android, xml, unit-testing, android-layout, screen-size

it's my first time to develop for Android and I almost finished the app but when I started testing it I faced some problems related to UI. I tested the app while programming it using galaxy s6 edge plus which has a 5.7" 1440x2560 screen, the app has many textviews and I used "sp" units for their text sizes and also used "dp" units for the margins between them. For some textviews I set their backgrounds as a drawable xml in which I set a value for their width and height using "dp" units instead of using wrap_content because I want the backgrounds to be larger than the text inside it so the user can easily touch it. I also made a large-layout folder where I put new xmls inside it with larger fonts so that they work will on tablet and they did, I tested the app on a tablet and it looks great using these xmls and also the app looks great on the 5.7" phone with the normal textviews. Then I tested it on 2 phones with smaller screens each of 5" one of them with Full HD resolution and the other with HD resolution and it looked good on both of them too but when I tested it on a phone with 5" screen but low resolution (480x800) the app looked terrible, textviews interfering with each other and the drawable backgrounds are too big, in short the whole UI is a mess.

What I need to know is whether I also have to test the app for more screen sizes below 5" or for other resolutions too? Because if this is the case then this means so much work!
[This is a screenshot of the code for the textview with the drawable background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2onc.png) 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check answer
[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644215/my-project-doesnt-support-multiple-devices-screen-view/25645141#25645141)

Answer (score 0):

Go through this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html and this too: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

I'm sure this will help you out.

If you still encounter any problem, feel free to ask again!

Peace.