# Android - how to adapt layouts for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, multiscreen

I provided different xml `layouts` (with same name) for different screen sizes - like `layout-sw320dp`, `layout-sw480dp` etc.
But when I try to change some properties in the specific layout in order to adapt UI for different devices - for example layout_height, layout_width, paddingRight, topMargin and so on - it still doesn't look good.
I suppouse that's because there is a screen sizes range (4-5") and different screen sizes read from `layout-sw320dp`. I tried on **Galaxy S4 - 5"** screen and on **Galaxy S3 Mini - 4"** screen. So on S4 evrything looks good but on S3 mini - doesn't - buttons are moved down, image not in the center.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644215/my-project-doesnt-support-multiple-devices-screen-view/25645141#25645141

Comment: Check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/34996396/2826147 @user5899501

Answer (score 1):

Use **dimens.xml** to assign Widths,Margins,padding. This xml is available in res/values folder. for different devices u can create different dimens. It simalar to having differnt Images for differnt Devices.

[**Source**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android#answer-32861248)

You have to create Different values folder for different screens . Like

```
values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi
values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi
values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 
values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi
values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi
values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

Check this Image :-

[image: SAMPLE Project View]

Comment: so I have to create not only layouts for different screens but also  different dimens for different screens? But if I already declared Widths,Margins,padding in different layouts - why have I create dimens also?